# Multilanguage site: language on URL as dir, file elsewhere. How to redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, multilingual

By now my site was only a one-language site.

I had my files on (suppose):

```
www.mysite.com/files/index.php
www.mysite.com/files/header.php
www.mysite.com/files/page1.php
www.mysite.com/files/page2.php
```

Now I added a multilanguage support to those files. All the words/texts are stored on the database and a php class complete the stuff.

By now I had (badly) on `header.php` this line:

```
define('LNG', 'en');
```

and I had a `header.php` file placed on each language directory:

```
www.mysite.com/en/header.php
www.mysite.com/de/header.php
...
```

and then I included the files depending on the `LNG` constant, e.g.

```
include_once "/files/page1.php?l=".LNG
```

but I know this is a very bad practise!

How can I solve this problem? I would mantain my files on `www.mysite.com/files/...` and then write the user language in the URL, so that the file can read the language from the url and load the right textes and words from the databases.

Sort of:

```
www.mysite.com/en/index.php
```

which in fact loads

```
www.mysite.com/index.php
```

with the correct language `en`. I'm able to get the `en` from the URL and define a constant on the page, but if I point to `www.mysite.com/en/index.php` I obviously get a `404`...

Answer (score 2):

### Dealing with multi-language web-applications

**`LANGUAGE CONSTANTS`** could be placed in language files within a language directory like this

```
/ languages
  en.php
  it.php
  ...
```

while language files may look as following

```
// en.php
define("THANK_YOU", "Thank you!");
define("PRODUCTS", "Products");
define("PRODUCT", "Product");
...

// it.php
define("THANK_YOU", "Grazie!");
define("PRODUCTS", "Prodotti");
define("PRODUCT", "Prodotto");
....
```

or they could be stored into database as shown below. I've used both but I prefer the first solution

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----
| constant   | en         | it         | ...
+------------+------------+------------+-----
| THANK_YOU  | Thank you! | Grazie!    |
| PRODUCTS   | Products   | Prodotti   |
| PRODUCT    | Product    | Prodotto   |
| ...        | ...        | ...        |
+------------+------------+------------+-----
```

**`FRIENDLY URLs`** may look like these below

```
http://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com/en
http://www.domain.com/it
http://www.domain.com/en/products
http://www.domain.com/it/prodotti
http://www.domain.com/en/product/our-best-product/555
http://www.domain.com/it/prodotto/il-nostro-miglior-prodotto/555
```

having in mind rules that should be defined in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/)?$                                    index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(products|prodotti)(/)?$                index.php?lang=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(product|prodotto)/(.*)/([0-9]+)(/)?$   index.php?lang=$1&action=$2&id=$4&mode=details [NC,L]

# these rules are for a demonstration purpose; otherwise, all three directives 
# could be written in one singe line / rule
```

or you can redirect the request (as following) to an entry point and parse it with `parse_url()`.

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**`ACCESSING THE lang VARIABLE`** - On multi-language projects variable `lang` has a special significance, otherwise it would be treated and passed around just like any other variable using `GET`, `POST`, `COOKIE`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `HTTP headers`, `HTTP referer`, `URL hash parameter`, `database session`, `APC (Alternative PHP Cache)` ...

If you care about `UX` and `SEO` the `lang` variable should be written within URL. I prefer using $_SESSION or $_GET and it should be pointed that some of the methods mentioned above doesn't work always or may get blocked by a Proxy.

The snippet below shows how to access it using $_SESSION or $_GET

```
// config.php
// ...
$cfgObj->default_language = "en";
// ...
$_SESSION["lang"] = isset($_GET["lang"]) ? $_GET["lang"] : $cfgObj->default_lang;
include($cfgObj->dir_languages . $_SESSION["lang"] . ".php");

// index.php
switch(isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : "default"){
    case PRODUCTS: case PRODUCT: case 3:
         // deal with products
         break:
    case ARTICLES: case ARTICLE: case 5:
         // deal with articles
         break:
    default: 
         // deal with short-links 
         // domain.com/3/555 <-- this would retrieve product with id 555 
         break;
}
```

**`DATABASE SCHEMA`** could be designed like following

```
+-----------------+       +-----------------------+       +--------------------+
| products        |       | products_to_languages |       | languages          |
+-----------------+       +-----------------------+       +--------------------+
| product_id [PK] |---|   | ptl_id           [PK] |   |---| language_id   [PK] |
| price           |   |---| product_id       [FK] |   |   | language_code      |
| status          |       | languge_id       [FK] |---|   +--------------------+
| ...             |       | product_name          |  
+-----------------+       | product_description   |
                          +-----------------------+

* I use language_code as a primary key as well, and an index on all foreign keys
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If have to write a `RewriteRule` for each page it becomes too long... What if I have 80 pages? I also prefer not to use sessions...

Comment: @Perocat My largest multilanguage project has fifteen languages. Having separate folders is a bad design; if you care about `UX` and `SEO` the `lang` variable should be within `URL`; language constants may be stored into database as well; the example above is showing how you can pass `lang` using `session` or `get` - you may use `post` or `cookie` but I wouldn't use them in this case;

Comment: the .htaccess above is an example - I believe all your eighty pages I could code in a few lines of `rules`:) - or you may everything redirect to index.php and parse the URL. Anyhow, in the meantime I'll update my answer to make it more useful :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I already have and index file where all requests are sent (if they not point directly to a file). I already had a database structure with the translation, and a class to access them and print them correctly on the page.
But take a real example:
`LINKS: /en/products/prod.php - /it/products/prod.php` and the file is here: `/files/products/prod.php`. How to maintain the original URL but load the file on the real location and read the `/en/` or the `/it/` from the URL within the file?

Comment: @Perocat That's also a good approach; but I don't prefer it in situation when people from the marketing department change things very often - when they change links, add additional teasing pages, when they redirect one page to another... - it would be killing not using .htaccess; this way the entry point is clean and safe :)